# How to subtract a number from a list?

Tags: excel

Subtracting in excel
to subtract 50 from {20,20 ,20} respectively we get {0,0,10}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nShbl.png)

Comment: What have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in first cell:

```
=(SUM($A$11:A11)-$A$10)*(SUM($A$11:A11)>$A$10)
```

and copy to the right.

[image]

The following formula can be used to correctly calculate the amount in cases where the initial number is less than the first value of the array:

```
=MIN((SUM($A$11:A11)-$A$10)*(SUM($A$11:A11)>$A$10);A11)
```

Comment: IF i put in A10 A Number less than 20 it doesn't work
can you please explain what does mean ">" after multiplication so I can try to edit by myself

Comment: =IF(B12>0,C11,(SUM($A$11:C11)-$A$10)*(SUM($A$11:C11)>$A$10))

Comment: @AliJaber the first part of the formula ```(SUM($A$11:A11)-$A$10)``` calculates the amount, the second part ```(SUM($A$11:A11)>$A$10)``` - checks if the amount is greater than the initial number and returns TRUE or FALSE (i.e. 1 or 0), which is multiplied by the first part to get the calculated amount or 0. I make a edit for cases where the initial number is less than the first value of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to fix the cell to copy. Refer the cell with 50 as e.g. $A$1 for the cell to be fixed.